# WordCount on Azure using hadoop and spark

Tags: scala, azure, hadoop, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

I have to run a simple wordcount on a cluster Hdinsight in Azure. I have created a cluster with hadoop and spark and i have already the jar file with the code, the problem that i don't know how to set-up the cluster and the right line of code to launch spark on Azure,I want to try different combination of nodes(workers , 2-4-8) to see how the program scale.

Every time i launch the app with spark-submit in mode yarn-client, it work but always with 2 executor and 1 core taking for 1gb input text file around 3 minute,also if i set more executor and more core he take the settings but he don't use that,so i think that the problem it's with the RDD, it don't split the input file in the right mode because it create only 2 task that start in 2 worknode and the other nodes remain inactive.

The jar file it's created with sbt package.

Command to launch Spark:

```
spark-submit --class "SimpleApp" --master yarn-client --num-executors 2 simpleapp_2.10-1.0.jar
```

WordCount Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import java.io._
import org.apache.hadoop.fs
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD


object SimpleApp {
def main(args: Array[String]){
//settingsparkcontext
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SimpleApp")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
//settingthewordtosearch
val word = "word"
//settingtime
val now = System.nanoTime
//settingtheinputfile
val input = sc.textFile("wasb://xxx@storage.blob.core.windows.net/dizionario1gb.txt")

//wordlookup
val splittedLines = input.map(line=>line.split(""))
val find = System.nanoTime
val tot = splittedLines.map(x => x.equals(word)).count()
val w=(System.nanoTime-find)/1000000
val rw=(System.nanoTime-now)/1000000
//reportingtheresultofexecutioninatxtfile
val writer = new FileWriter("D:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\File\\output.txt",true)
try {
writer.write("Word found "+tot+" time total "+rw+" mstimesearch "+w+" time read "+(rw-w)+"\n")
}
finally writer.close()
//terminatingthesparkserver
sc.stop()
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Level of Parallelism**

"Clusters will not be fully utilized unless you set the level of parallelism for each operation high enough. Spark automatically sets the number of “map” tasks to run on each file according to its size (though you can control it through optional parameters to SparkContext.textFile, etc) You can pass the level of parallelism as a second argument (see the spark.PairRDDFunctions documentation), or set the config property spark.default.parallelism to change the default. In general, we recommend 2-3 tasks per CPU core in your cluster."

**Source:**
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/tuning.html

Comment: thanks a lot for your the answer, unfortunately, I have tried to put this setting and despite spark take the set spark.default.parallelism with for example 2,4,8 (see it from the settings of application master on sparkUI) but unfortunately does not change, it always seems to go though with the default settings with one core each worker 2 , maybe we do not put some initial configuration that does not allow the proper functioning of spark, maybe have you other ideas?

Comment: If you increase the data size do you see the same issues? I'm thinking that 1gb file may be too small to see a big difference...

Comment: I have tested with one 10gb text file but it still works with the same 2 executor with 1 core each one. So i think that we can keep out the hypotesis about the dimension of the input file.